# How to get a dataset that contains both the categorical data and continuous data into user defined metric function in DBSCAN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I have a dataset with continuous and categorical values. I would like to write a function as a metric in DBSCAN which uses the same Euclidean distance for continuous and to deal with categorical values it must identify the whole string value with other string value. If these 2 values are equal it must give the distance as 0 if they are not equal then it should produce one as the result. When I am trying to write the user defined function for metric, it is not at all passing the data to my function. It throwing error like "could not convert string to float: "'second'" "? Is there any way to pass the data to my function?
[image]

The dataframe looks like:

```
        sundar call      raju   ram     sony  tintu  banti
points                                                    
x1         0.6  '0'   'first'  0.93   'lion'   0.34   0.98
x2         0.7  '1'  'second'  0.47    'cat'   0.43   0.76
x3         0.4  '0'   'third'  0.87  'tiger'   0.24   0.10
x4         0.6  '0'   'first'  0.93   'lion'   0.34   0.98
x5         0.5  '1'   'first'  0.32  'tiger'   0.09   0.99
x6         0.4  '0'   'third'  0.78  'tiger'   0.18   0.17
x7         0.5  '1'  'second'  0.98    'cat'   0.47   0.78
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should initialize DBSCAN with "precomputed" metric:

```
dbscan = sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN(metric="precomputed")
```

(other parameters are omitted). Then calculate metrics between all the samples and get the matrix of shape `[n_samples, n_samples]`.

```
X = user_defined_metric(data, data)
```

then use this data to fit DBSCAN:

```
labels = dbscan.fit_predict(X)
```

According to sklearn documentation,

```
fit_predict(X, y=None, sample_weight=None)

Performs clustering on X and returns cluster labels.
Parameters: 
X : array or sparse (CSR) matrix of shape (n_samples, n_features), or array of shape (n_samples, n_samples)
    A feature array, or array of distances between samples if metric='precomputed'.
```

Second case - array of shape `[n_samples, n_samples]` is yours.

Comment: But again string data is not being passed into my function(in your case its user_defined_metric(data, data)). it throws another error saying that :  Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: @Vamshi can you provide an example of your data, i.e. one or two rows from data frame, and a definition of your metric (code)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I made some mistake by not implementing it completely. So, when DBSCAN tries to find distance matrix which I have not implemented and returning an error.

Comment: @Vamshi I'm glad to know it :)